# Vivarium Tank Moving

Tags: aquarium, frogs

I have a 20 gallon tank vivarium which is not filled with water and is only 1/5 filled with substrate, rocks, etc. I keep my tank on my bookshelf next to my window and occasionally move it to my desk where the outside air can flow into the tank.

Recently, I noticed that a line formed in the middle of the tank casing (the black part of the tank found on the top and bottom of the tank). I believe that this line formed because of my moving of the tank around and so the pressure when I move the tank builds up in the middle of the tank.

Will my tank crack and explode if I keep doing this? I watched some videos online and read some other posts saying that the silicone may weaken if you move your tank around too much. Is this true?

Comment: Can you post a picture? What material is the bottom made off?

Comment: One thing to consider is not just the weakening of the silicone but also the glass. I've seen the glass on tanks crack because the stand is uneven so the pressure is not distributed across the whole tank.

Answer (score 1):

When you move a tank, and hold it only on the sides, there indeed will be a lot of pressure on the bottom and it could cause damage. Especially if the tank is pretty large (like yours seem to be) and not empty. 
 Normally you should try to make a tank as empty as possible when moving it. Remove any big rocks or ornaments, and remove as much water as possible (important when moving a fishtank). 
And then try to put some counter pressure by holding it with 1 hand on the bottom. 
 But that might not be easy to do with a larger tank (I can do this with my 30 litre fishtank, but I would not do it with anything bigger than that)
Even better would be to slide the tank on a wooden plank, and then carry the plank in stead of the tank. 
Since you seem to move it rather regularly, and your tank is already damaged, I think it's indeed important that you start doing that now to avoid further damage. 
I would even advice that you even put it on a nice plank permanently. It will make moving it a lot easier. 
Just make sure the plank is thick enough, so it won't bend either.